# How to start Akka Actors since 2.0?

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I'm using **Akka Actors** and I'm trying to update my code to use the latest 2.0 milestone. The API changed somewhat, for example the creation of Actors now works via something called an `ActorSystem`.

Starting and stopping actors changed as well - the latter is available via the `ActorSystems` methods `.stop(..)` and `.shutdown()`. But I can for the life of me not figure out how to start them...
The documentation is good, but seems to be missing some important points. I feel kinda stupid to ask, but how do you start actors in your Akka 2.0 environment? If I understood correctly actors who have a 'parent' are started when this parent is started - but what about the top level actor(s)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Akka 2.0, there is no need for a start() method because Actors are started as soon as you instantiate them in the context of an `ActorSystem` (or another `Actor`) -- but you need to instantiate them with one of the provided methods of `ActorSystem` or an `Actor`'s `context`.

So, for example, if you have an `Actor` subclass called `MyClass`, you could start it with:

```
val system = ActorSystem()
val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor])
```

or, if your actor took constructor arguments:

```
val myActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor("arg1"))
```

or, if you were in the body of another Actor,

```
val myActor = context.actorOf(Props(new Actor("arg1"))
```

and then your actor could immediately receive messages, e.g.

```
myActor ! MyMessage
```

Even your top level actors are started immediately, as all Actors in 2.0 are automatically in a supervision hierarchy.  As soon as the actor is instantiated with the `ActorSystem`, it's ready to receive messages.

Comment: Oh, I guess it was to easy for me to understand... *feelingstupid* Thank you :)

Comment: No problem!  It wasn't a stupid question at all -- the new behavior relies on two new features at once (automatic supervision and automatic start) which is confusing at first if you're used to the 1.2 or 1.3 API.  But it's simpler once you're used to it.